# select table forcing table scan on sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that I want to perform a `select * from table`, however, for some reason, this table hangs at a specific point everytime. When I did a  `select * into #mytemp from table` and then `select * from #mytemp`, this second select was way faster than select direct from the table. Since the select from the temp table was faster, I want to perform a table scan on the main one.

Notes:

table have a columnstore index and thats the one that is being used on `select * from table` (checked on execution plan)

Comment: Please add the execution plan to [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan) and link it in your Post.

Answer (score 0):

> for some reason, this table hangs at a specific point everytime

That can happen if your database is broken. Use [`dbcc checktable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checktable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to prove or disprove it.

It can also be a problem with the client which supposed to show the result from `select * from table`. The workaround with temp table, you found, can hide offending records, try doing `select count(*) from table` and `select count(*) from #mytemp` - there could be difference.

You can also try to copy data into a new table: `select * into newtable from table` and check for differences between old-new tables if the old one is indeed broken.

> table have a columnstore index

Is there a difference between `select *`, `select column_in_index`, and `select columns_not_in_the_index`? The problem can be in the index itself.

BTW, the `select * into #mytemp from table` does a silent remove of the columnstore, the temp table is always a normal rowstore table.

You can try to remove and recreate the index using [`drop index`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/drop-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and [`create columnstore index`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-columnstore-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) if you find the difference.